# Xcode + xcodebuild complains about multiline string literal when exporting for localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

I have something like

```
NSLocalizedString(@"key", 
                  @"comments in "
                  @"multiple lines")
```

in one of my files and when I attempt to export the project that contains the file via

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [[-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>]]
```

I get an error message like this:

```
Bad entry in file <file_name>.m (line = 35): Argument is not a literal string.
```

In my experiment, this issue goes away when I make the comment a single line literal.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and knows more about what is going on here? Xcode's other tool for localization, genstrings, seems to handle this fine.

Comment: Just for clarification, I am running Xcode 6.4.

Comment: So the error tells you exactly what is going on, and you have found the way to address it. Not sure what you are asking. You could also use `stringByAppendingString:` here, of course.